# Laravel 5.4 delete table row and rows from related table

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, relationships

When i delete a row from a groups table, i want the function to also delete all relation mapping from table group_user. For example, if i delete group with id 4, all rows in group_user table with group_id 4 are deleted as well. Tables below:

```html
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->boolean('approved')->default(false);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
 Schema::create('groups', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('course_id');
            $table->timestamp('start_date')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('end_date')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
  Schema::create('group_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('group_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Currently using this function in group controller, but it only deletes from groups table:

```html
function deleteGroup($id){
  $group = Group::find($id);
  $group->delete();
  return redirect()->back();
 }
```

Comment: I think you want some definition like: `$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('gropu')->onDelete('cascade');`

Comment: @mkaatman sorry I didn't see your comment ;) I think your comment is right way solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table storage engine type is innodb you can try in your migrations to set correct relationships and all will be done in the database layer.

```
Schema::create('group_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('group_id');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users'))
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users'))
                ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Comment: InnoDB is a storage engine for the database management system (MySQL, MariaDB), but if I am not mistaken laravel by default use innoDB for migrations.